# How to build an Actix Web TestServer with state and a factory?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

In the [actix-web documentation](https://github.com/actix/actix-website/blob/master/content/docs/testing.md), there are two examples on how to build a [`TestServer`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.7.18/actix_web/test/struct.TestServer.html) with either a **factory function**:

```rust
use actix_web::{http, test, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse};
// ...

fn main() {
    let mut srv = test::TestServer::with_factory(create_app);
    // ...
}
```

or with application **state**:

```rust
fn test() {
    let srv = TestServer::build_with_state(|| {
    // ...
    });

    // run tests
}
```

I would like to build a `TestServer` with state **and** using a factory function, but haven't been successful so far.

How can this be accomplished?